# How to bulk update child objects with Django Rest?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to construct a `ViewSet` that does partial updates:

```
class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for retrieving an invoice.
    """

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        # my retrieve logic here

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        # unsure about how to do bulk update here
```

Essentially, my `Invoice` model has child objects (`InvoiceUser` instances) and I wish to update them as well when doing a patch request to my Invoice API endpoint.

My Invoice Serializer looks like this:

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    invoice_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_invoice_users')

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = (
            "status",
            "invoice_users",
            # other stuff here 
        )

    def get_invoice_users(self, obj):
        invoice_users = obj.invoice_users.all()
        return InvoiceUserSerializer(invoice_users, many=True).data
```

When calling the `retrieve` function on `InvoiceViewSet`, it returns something like this:

```
{
    "status": "approved",
    "invoice_users": [
        {
            "id": 45,
            "hours": "29.0",
            "hour_cost": "5.00",
            "invoice": 35,
            "project_user": 30
        },
        {
            "id": 46,
            "hours": "109.0",
            "hour_cost": "10.00",
            "invoice": 35,
            "project_user": 36
        }
    ],
    // other stuff

}
```

if I change a field that sits on the `Invoice` model, say the `status` field as an example above, and do a patch request, it updates that value just fine. However, how would I update the child objects (`invoice_users`) when changing any of their value?

I tried

```
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoice, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        print(serializer.validated_data)
```

But this only prints out the data from the `Invoice` model, not its corresponding children

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is the most Django way of doing things, but I found a work-around using Djangos bulk update method

```
    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        invoice =  Invoice.objects.get(pk=pk)
        
        invoice_users_update = []
        for invoice_user in request.data['invoice_users']:
            user = InvoiceUser.objects.get(id=invoice_user["id"])
            user.hours = invoice_user["hours"]
            user.hour_cost = invoice_user["hour_cost"]
            invoice_users_update.append(user)
        
        InvoiceUser.objects.bulk_update(invoice_users_update, ["hours", "hour_cost"])
        
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(invoice, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```